# RangeError: Invalid array length at array spread

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, array-splice

I have a rather standard item hydration function that throws "**RangeError: Invalid array length**". Unfortunately this happens very rarely and in the production so it's hard to catch the input params.

This is the function:

```js
function setProgress(items: SomeType[], id: string, someProperty: string) {
  const index = items.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
  const newItem: SomeType = {...items[index], someProperty };

  return [...items.slice(0, index), newItem, ...items.slice(index + 1); 
}
```

And this is what is transpiles to (non-uglified):

```
function setProgress(items, id, someProperty) {
  var index = items.findIndex(function(e) {
      return items.id === id
    }), 
    newItem = Object.assign({}, items[index], {
      someProperty: someProperty
    });
  return items.slice(0, index).concat([newItem], items.slice(index + 1));
}
```

I've tried playing with different values but I cannot reproduce this error.

Any idea what and how could cause this?

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this function? "Invalid length" is only raised when you do `Array(-1)` or `.length=-1`, neither of which is the case.

Comment: That is what's puzzling me. Chrome reports error on the return line. And this function is part of the reducer so the inputs are quite strictly controlled.

Comment: When I look at the minified code, the only Array(o) are to be found in angular's reflective-injector and RxJS forkJoin and withLatestFrom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in an unhandled corner case when the index is `-1`.
Instead of replacing an element, it would double the size of an array. This would eventually lead to stack overflow and hitting the limit of the array size.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue occur with the following scenario, while trying to spread an array-like object:

```
let borken = [...this.state.data.get("tags"), newTag]

// immutablejs toJS() converts the array-like into an array.
let worken = [...this.state.data.get("tags").toJS(), newTag]
```

A few examples of how to get this error:

```js
// example 1
Array(NaN)

// example 2
let a = []
a.length = a.length  - 1

// example 3 setting .length to > 2^32
let b = [];
b.length = Math.pow(2, 32);
```

In my case, it was calling the following `__spreadArrays`:

```js
var __spreadArrays = (undefined && undefined.__spreadArrays) || function () {
    for (var s = 0, i = 0, il = arguments.length; i < il; i++) s += arguments[i].length;
    for (var r = Array(s), k = 0, i = 0; i < il; i++)
        for (var a = arguments[i], j = 0, jl = a.length; j < jl; j++, k++)
            r[k] = a[j];
    return r;
};
```

Where `var r = Array(s)` and `s` was `NaN`